# Execute method inside implemented interface in multiple modular plugins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, plugins, asp.net-core

I am implementing a plugin architecture for a .net core MVC application.
A requirement of each of my plugins is to implement an interface from a centralised core library in which the main mvc application will then call the implemented interface method in each of the plugin modules.

Now I get my list of assemblies and from my .NET Core Startup file call the LoadModuleAssemblies method:

```
public static void LoadModuleAssemblies(IServiceCollection services, FileInfo[] assemblyList)
        {
            foreach (var dir in assemblyList)
            {
                if (dir.Name != CoreLibFile)
                {
                    var asl = new AssemblyLoader(dir.DirectoryName);
                    var assembly = asl.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dir.FullName);
                    var implementedList = assembly.GetTypes()
                        .Where(x => x.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IModule))).ToList();
                    if (implementedList.Any())
                    {
                        services.AddMvc()
                            .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
                            .AddControllersAsServices();

                        //Unsure how to load IModule implemented interface and call GetProperties method in the interface. 

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My Interface looks like this:

```
public interface IModule
    {
        ModuleProperties GetProperties();
        List<string> GetViews();
    }
```

I want to be able to call the GetProperties method in the implemented IModule for each of my plugins.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Reflection` to create instances of the plugin, and then call its `GetProperties` method

```
if (implementedList.Any())
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
        .AddControllersAsServices();

    foreach(var type in implementedList)
    {
         var module = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IModule;
         var properties = module.GetProperties();
         var views = module. GetViews();

         //make use of the properties and views...
    }
}
```